# Can't fix null pointer exception

Tags: java

I am getting a null pointer exception on my `nameA = view.getHumanName(nameB);` line in my model class. I am trying to establish `nameA` using the `getHumanName` method from the view class. I also attempted to add in `this.view = view` to the model constructor but that does not fix the issue. Why am I getting this error in this instance?

**Model class and instance variable:**

```
   public Model(Dice die){
      nameB = "Toby";
      nameA = view.getHumanName(nameB);
      p1 = new Player(nameA);
      p2 = new Player(nameB);
      this.die = die;
   }
}
```

**Method in View class:**

```
public String getHumanName(String compName){
   System.out.println("Enter a name for the human player: ");
   String humanName = scan.nextLine();
   while(humanName.equals(compName) || humanName.trim().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("The human player cannot have the same name as the computer player or be blank. Enter a new name for the human player: ");
        humanName = scan.nextLine();
   }
   return humanName;
}
```

Comment: Where is your object initialization for the View ref: https://www.javaworld.com/article/3040564/learn-java/java-101-class-and-object-initialization-in-java.html

Comment: Your view isn't yet instantiated when you call `view.getHumanName`, You must create the view object before using it (`view = new View ()`)

Comment: Most definalty a duplicate. there is 2 easy ways to fix it. One is intatiate view, 2nd is make the method static. I assume you are learning about MVC. Also read up about the role of the controller.

Comment: @MehdiB. Yeah I tried that and am still getting the error i am not sure why

Comment: Side note: `Scanner.hasNextLine()` must return true before you can safely call `Scanner.getNextLine`.

Comment: have you initialized the scanner object, if not `scan = new Scanner(System.in)`

Comment: As @Roushan said have you initialized the scan and could you post the stack trace by edit the question.

Comment: For future reference, you should post a [mcve] for any question. This means that your code should produce the same exact error that you are asking about. The code in this question has many compiler errors so we cannot see the NPE you need help with.

Comment: @Roushan Yeah i initialize the scanner in my view class so that isn't the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign anything to view, so by default it is initialised as null. Try putting the following in your constructor:

```
view = new View();
```

Comment: Can you please show the full Model class then?

Comment: I got it working!